# How do I open gnome-terminal in a maximized window by default?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 11.04. When I launch `gnome-terminal`, how do I make it open in a maximized window by default?

Currently it's only taking part of the screen and I always have to maximise the window.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a command line option:

```
gnome-terminal --maximize
```

Also,

```
gnome-terminal --full-screen
```

If you want to modify a shortcut, you should be able to right-click the shortcut and select Properties, then add the option there.